# Python creating worker queues

Tags: python, multithreading, beautifulsoup

I am data mining a website using [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). The first page is [Scoutmob's map](http://scoutmob.com/?force=1), where I grab each city, open up the page, and grab the URL of each deal in that city.

Currently I'm not using threads and everything is being processed serially. For about all 500 deals (from all cities), my program currently takes about 400 seconds.

For practice, I wanted to modify my code to use threading. I have read up some [tutorials and examples](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-threadingpython/) on how to create queues in Python, but I don't want to create 500 threads to process 500 URLs.

Instead I want to create about 20 (worker) threads to process all the URLs. **Can someone show me an example how 20 threads can process 500 URL in a queue?**

I want each worker to grab an unprocessed URL from the queue, and data mine, then once finished, work on another unprocessed URL. Each worker only exit when there is no more URLs in the queue.

By the way, while each worker is data mining, it also writes the content to a database. So there might be issues with threading in the database, but that is another question for another day :-).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "I want each worker to grab an unprocessed URL from the queue, and data mine, then once finished, " is the answer.  What more do you want to know?  Are you asking how to use the get method of a queue?

Comment: I guess I wasn't how threads will kept "open" until there is no more items in the queue. Do I need to completely populate the queue first, so can I create like a "live" conenction to the queue, and the threads keeps working until I tell it to stop?

Comment: I'm unable to understand your question.  Are you assuming that the threads all magically stop when the queue is empty?  Why would they do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your example creating worker queues is probably overkill. You might have better luck if you grab the rss feed published for each of the pages rather than trying to parse the HTML which is slower. I slapped together the quick little script below that parses it in a total of ~13 seconds... ~8 seconds to grab the cities and ~5 seconds to parse *all* the rss feeds.

In today's run it grabs 310 total deals from 13 cities (there are a total of 20 cities listed, but 7 of them are listed as "coming soon").

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from lxml import etree, html
from urlparse import urljoin
import time

t = time.time()
base = 'http://scoutmob.com/'
main = html.parse(base)
cities = [x.split('?')[0] for x in main.xpath("//a[starts-with(@class, 'cities-')]/@href")]
urls = [urljoin(base, x + '/today') for x in cities]
docs = [html.parse(url) for url in urls]
feeds = [doc.xpath("//link[@rel='alternate']/@href")[0] for doc in docs]
# filter out the "coming soon" feeds
feeds = [x for x in feeds if x != 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/scoutmob']
print time.time() - t
print len(cities), cities
print len(feeds), feeds

t = time.time()
items = [etree.parse(x).xpath("//item") for x in feeds]
print time.time() - t
count = sum(map(len, items))
print count
```

Yields this output:

```
7.79690480232
20 ['/atlanta', '/new-york', '/san-francisco', '/washington-dc', '/charlotte', '/miami', '/philadelphia', '/houston', '/minneapolis', '/phoenix', '/san-diego', '/nashville', '/austin', '/boston', '/chicago', '/dallas', '/denver', '/los-angeles', '/seattle', '/portland']
13 ['http://feeds.feedburner.com/scoutmob/atl', 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/scoutmob/nyc', 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/scoutmob/sf', 'http://scoutmob.com/washington-dc.rss', 'http://scoutmob.com/nashville.rss', 'http://scoutmob.com/austin.rss', 'http://scoutmob.com/boston.rss', 'http://scoutmob.com/chicago.rss', 'http://scoutmob.com/dallas.rss', 'http://scoutmob.com/denver.rss', 'http://scoutmob.com/los-angeles.rss', 'http://scoutmob.com/seattle.rss', 'http://scoutmob.com/portland.rss']
4.76977992058
310
```

Comment: Thank for the reply, but something isn't right... There are 556 deals from all cities so far. Reading just the RSS feed is insufficient for me since the RSS feed doesn't tell me enough info per deal (such as business address and phone numnber). Also it seems the RSS feeds also has news articles, which I don't care. So I still need to open each invdividual deal page. And is your code is pretty much taking the RSS feed and using Xpath to grab all info?

Answer (score 0):

Just implement it. You've pretty much talked yourself through the answer right there

> I want each worker to grab an unprocessed URL from the queue, and data mine, then once finished, work on another unprocessed URL. Each worker only exit when there is no more URLs in the queue.